# Program doesn't start after including CefSharp (only on a second PC or on someone else's)

Tags: c#, cefsharp

It does start on my main that I made it on. I tested on Win7, my main is Wi10 and my friend also tested it on Win10. First, I got this error: [Error that I'd recieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o27w2.png)  and then I read that it can be fixed by [setting "Copy local" true in all of the CefSharp reference properties.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOlwY.png)  After that my program just stops working instantly and now it just doesn't start it only shows the crashing if I start it as admin. It still works on my main tho. And the code is nothing too extreme I just included the browser and disabled the right click.

```
 public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://google.com/");
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        browser.MenuHandler = new CustomMenuHandler();

    }
    public class CustomMenuHandler : CefSharp.IContextMenuHandler
    {
        public void OnBeforeContextMenu(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model)
        {
            model.Clear();
        }

        public bool OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
        {

            return false;
        }

        public void OnContextMenuDismissed(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame)
        {

        }

        public bool RunContextMenu(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model, IRunContextMenuCallback callback)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "it only shows the crashing" This evidence is the most crucial part of your question and you skimmed right over it.

Comment: Did you add CefSharp to the GAC like the error told you?

Comment: If I add it on my main, will it affect the installed verison by the users?

Comment: CefSharp doesn't contain a dialogue telling you to use the GAC? What's generating that error?

Comment: I made a new project file and as soon as I added cefsharp it showed that error on a second PC. But that PC has Visual C++ and .NET framework and everything.

Comment: What version of VC++ do you have installed? x86 or x64? What architecture is your app targeting? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/63/NuGet/Readme.txt#L28